# How do I detect the name of a random UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a random image popping up using this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay:2, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromTop, animations: {
        self.imageView.alpha = 2
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "gameBall\(arc4random_uniform(12) + 1).png")      
    })
}
```

When the user swipes down I want to detect the name of the image and then if the correct image is swiped down i want it to say "1 point!" if the wrong image is swiped down i want it to say "Game Over!" I already have some code that does not work because it only says "Game Over!" where ever I swipe:

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        switch sender.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
            if imageView == UIImage(named: "gameBall2.png"){
                println("1 point!")
            }else{
                println("Game Over!")
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    var swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Comparing a `UIImageView` to a `UIImage` will never succeed.

Comment: So there is no way to do this?

Comment: You can try comparing the image view's image to the `UIImage`.

Comment: the image view's image?

Comment: No, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you may want to set the tag of the imageView.

```
let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(12) + 1)
self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "gameBall\(randomNumber).png")
self.imageView.tag = randomNumber
```

Now you can compare the tag in your if condition.

```
if self.imageView.tag == 2 {
    println("1 point!")
} else {
    println("Game Over!")
}
```